# What is a good way to organise my data after importing

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have measurements for experiments with different materials which I would like to import in python to be able to analyse later. The raw data I was provided has a folder for each material. In each folder there are possibly subfolders for different forms of the material, and the last level is folders whose name contains the values of 2 different facets of the experiment that could be varied. Finally those folders contain raw data files for multiple runs of the same experiment which I know how to import into pandas data frames.

The data contained in those raw data files is essentially a table with measurements at different points in time during the experimental run. A sample raw file could be found [here](https://github.com/sgadzhev/importing_dat_files/blob/master/raw_file.dat) and I've included a sample folder structure [here](https://github.com/sgadzhev/importing_dat_files/tree/master/Sample_Folders)(the txt files are just to allow me to create folders). I intend to perform some sort of curve fit on each of those data sets, I appreciate it is not actual data I'm sharing and I'm not very particular on the context but I hope this is not too important for the more general question about organising such structure.

**I am looking for a way to traverse this structure and import the data in a sensible structured way to support further analysis.** I was thinking I could use nested dictionary with a dictionary for the material and then further subdictionaries for each of the experimental conditions, but dictionaries are not great for slicing data. Ideally, I would like to be able to call the data for all runs where, say, the mill speed was 5 units.

I am a beginner with data analysis in python so I could imagine clarifications will be needed, I will try to update promptly.

Comment: it would be helpful to provide a visual example / extract of the data

Comment: In a previous  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221143/how-can-read-dat-file-containing-multiple-tables-into-a-pandas-data-frame) I've asked you could see what the data is like, 
essentially it is just a table with measurements at different points in time during the experimental run. If you would like clarifications on how the raw data is organised into folders instead, let me know.

Comment: You're the one wanting answers, you can hardly expect us to go through your old questions to find information about this one. Your questions should be self-contained.

Comment: That's a good point, I will edit it to include the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without having more information about the data but you could perhaps have a custom class for this or even classes e.g. one for the material and one for the experiments. If you provide a sample structure I can amend the answer to include some sample code.

Edit: this should provide you with a basic structure:

```
class MaterialCollection:
    def __init__(self,name,mats):
        self.name = name
        self.materials = materials #an array of Materials

    def __getitem__(self,i): #allows you to do MaterialsCollection['Iron']
        for mat in self.materials:
            if mat.name == i:
                return mat

class Material:
    def __init__(self, name,children):
        self.name = name
        self.submaterials = children #an array of submaterials


class SubMaterial:
    def __init__(self,name,parentMaterial,experiments ):
        self.name = name
        self.parentMaterial= parentMaterial
        self.experiments = experiments #an array of experiments



class Experiment:
    def __init__(self,filename,idi,submaterial):
        self.filename = filename
        self.idi = idi
        self.submaterial= submaterial
        self.material = self.submaterial.parentMaterial


    def parseData(self):
        f = open(filename,'rb').read()
        #do something with your data ex:
        self.speed = f[0]
```

Comment: In a comment to the question I've linked to a sample of what the individual raw data files consist of, I will try to replicate a folder structure and upload it to github.

Comment: Let me know if the above makes sense, essentially you will then read all folders (as Materials) in a MaterialsCollection and then for each folder parse the SubMaterials etc

Comment: Hi, thank you for the code. I have not used classes before so I may need some time before I can understand your suggestion. I'll read up on these and get back to you but from what I've read so far it does seem like a promising solution. Also I've updated the original post with links to a sample folder structure and sample raw file if that is helpful.

Comment: Yah so given your folder structure this should work, if needed you can retag me and I can give you more pointers on how to read the data correctly into structures :)

Answer (score 0):

> a sensible structured way to support further analysis

A sensible, structured way to store data is in a database.

I don't want to add to the mental load if you are only just getting used to Python but this is an ideal use case for a relational database.  Personally, I would use SQLite and the sqlite3 Python package.

In SQL, create a table something like this:

```sql
create table experimental_results (
    material_name text,
    facet_1_name  text,
    facet_2_name  text,
    date_of_run   date,
    v1            real,
    v2            real,
    ...           
);
```

And then follow the [SQLite examples](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/) to query the data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, from common knowledge about what it does, I did suspect it may boil down to SQL after all. I may try this approach as well but it feels like it will take longer to get comfortable with it that the solution above with classes.